# Creating and using a static library with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

I am trying to first create a static library and then link it to an executable using CMake. My project file structure looks like this:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── build
├── lib
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── build
│   ├── include
│   │   └── Point.hpp
│   └── src
│       └── Point.cpp
└── mainApp.cpp
```

I first build the library like so.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project(CAST3)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

include_directories(include)

file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
add_library(CAST3 STATIC ${SOURCES})
```

However, when i try to link the library to my executable I get an error.

This is my executable

```
#include"Point.hpp"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Point p = Point(1,2,3);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my CMake file to link the library to the executable.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project (CAST3)
set ( PROJECT_LINK_LIBS libCAST3.a )
link_directories( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/build)
add_executable(libtest mainApp.cpp)
target_link_libraries(libtest ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBS} )
```

When I run that I get the this error

```
/mainApp.cpp:1:9: fatal error: 'Point.hpp' file not found
#include"Point.hpp"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/libtest.dir/mainApp.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/libtest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)` - are you sure you are using that old cmake? It's from 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I missing?

You are missing `target_include_directories(CAST3 PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)` inside `lib/CMakeLists.txt`.

You are missing `add_subdirectory(lib)` from root `CMakeLists.txt`.

The `set ( PROJECT_LINK_LIBS libCAST3.a )` and `target_link_libraries(libtest ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBS} )` and `link_directories( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/build)` could be removed. Then you are missing just `target_link_libraries(libtest PUBLIC CAST3)`. Cmake will automatically find the proper .a file and propagate include paths with `target_link_libraries`.

So your `lib/CMakeLists.txt` could look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0) # I would advise to update
project(CAST3)
include_directories(include)
file(GLOB sources src/*.cpp) # upper case variable names reserved for exported variables by convention
add_library(CAST3 ${sources}) # STATIC by default
target_include_directories(CAST3 PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

And root `CMakeLists.txt` could look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0) # I would advise to update
project(CAST3)
add_subdirectory(lib)
add_executable(libtest mainApp.cpp)
target_link_libraries(libtest CAST3)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the fast reply. I am new to CMake, and this helped a lot.